# Solution this error: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb?

Tags: django, mysql-connector

I'm not professional to work in Django
I know this problem has been asked a lot in StackOverflow but I need the end answer to fix this problem with me.
I'm using Django 1.9 and python 2.7 and I need to link both of MySQL with Django, I tried everything and I had taken a long time looking for the end of the solution but it's bad. I got nothing
I used Pymysql, Mysql-connector-python, Mysql-connector and I tried to install Mysqlclient but I get failed and now I get really disappointed because of this problem. so, this is my last trying and I get this error too:
**Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb** [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVD3v.png). so, How can I run MySQL in any way I mentioned above (Pymysql, etc....)
sorry, I'm not fluent at English if there was any wrong

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'students', # the name of database
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install `mysqlclient` module using `pip install mysqlclient` command.

You might need to install MYSQL development libraries to install `mysqlclient`.

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev # Debian / Ubuntu
sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel # Red Hat / CentOS
brew install mysql-client # macOS (Homebrew)
```

[Link](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)

Hope this helps.

Edit: You can also download .whl file directly from [Link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient), and then run `pip install downloaded_whl_file` to install that.

Comment: I get that error
**Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error**
I'd to mention that i'm using windows not Mac

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin can you provide full error message ?

Comment: I try to find any way to send the error message it has a huge context. so, I got my help from Github .
this link contains the errors that appear with me. [link](https://github.com/AbdelhamedAbdin/message_error/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Try to download .whl file directly from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient, and then run "pip install downloaded_whl_file" to install that. I have also updated the answer. let me know if you still face the issue.

Comment: sorry for bothering you but there is a new problem [link](https://github.com/AbdelhamedAbdin/message_error/blob/master/no%20matching%20dist)
where can I get requirement.txt 
as it needs

Comment: @abdelhamedabdin you are downloading and installing wrong file, on given link there are two files mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp27‑cp27m‑win32.whl and mysqlclient‑1.4.6‑cp27‑cp27m‑win_amd64.whl for Python2.7, download according to your platform and install that using "pip install file". let me know if you still face any issue.